# failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED, only on Tuesdays

Tags: ssd, freeze, crash

I know this error has been had by many people, but I couldn't find any examples of it happening routinely on a specific day of the week. It caused Ubuntu to freeze.

```
failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

This only ever happens on Tuesday for me, several times in the morning, usually about 10-20 minutes after booting, and after 2-3 forced shutdowns, it eventually stops, until next week.

I've had a look in the crontab for anything, but I'm not sure what to look for.

**For comments:**

```
$ systemctl list-timers
Tue 2018-08-14 06:23:06 BST  14h left      Mon 2018-08-13 09:31:04 BST  6h ago    apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.ser
Tue 2018-08-14 09:45:46 BST  17h left      Mon 2018-08-13 09:45:46 BST  6h ago    systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clea

$ ls -al /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 86 Apr 13  2016 /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim

$ cat /etc/crontab | grep weekly
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
```

**Kernel logs**

```
/var/log/kern.log.1:80:Aug  7 09:44:42 pc kernel: [  707.304054] ata7.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/kern.log.1:107:Aug  7 09:45:15 pc kernel: [  740.071623] ata7.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/kern.log.1:111:Aug  7 09:45:15 pc kernel: [  740.071665] ata7.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
/var/log/kern.log.1:126:Aug  7 09:45:47 pc kernel: [  772.838856] ata7.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
```

Comment: If it is planned, then it may be caused by Cron or SystemD timers. I think it is TRIM-related. Please add output of `systemctl list-timers`, `ls -al /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` and  `cat /etc/crontab | grep weekly`.

Comment: @N0rbert added.

Comment: I do not see any clues about Tuesday. Try to search `/var/log` for occurencies of `READ FPDMA QUEUED`.

Comment: @N0rbert i've added the logs, and before it just happened, i went into the F2 terminal a waited for it to happen, then ran `top` and there was `fstrim`.

Comment: Just curious what is your SSD model? And does it support TRIM on hardware level? Please add output of `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM` (change `/dev/sda` to the appropriate rootfs device) to the question. And check [this paragraph](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive#Resolving_NCQ_errors).

Answer (score 0):

As we have discovered that the issue is caused by `fstrim`, let's disable it:

```
sudo rm /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

And then see how system works after disabling TRIM.

**Note:** my system is installed on Samsung PRO SSD.

```
$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM
   *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 8 blocks)
   *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
```

I have both [periodic TRIM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive#Periodic_TRIM) (`fstrim` cron-job) and [continuous TRIM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive#Continuous_TRIM) (`discard` option in `/etc/fstab`). It operates without issues.